# chinese mobile software development?

Tags: mobile, localization, firmware, cjk

As per my assumption () there are hundreds of millions of Chinese mobile phones (or clones of brand phones) out there. And it seems firmware and OS of those mobile phones are same. Those phones only differ in their design and may be hardware.

I was wondering if there is any development kit or software development support for those mobile phones. What is that OS and/or firmware inside those phones? Are those open source or available online anyway? Do those phones support java? Where to get more information about those phones and their software online?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a lot of chinesemobile phones using Win Mobile OS

Comment: @adopilot it is not real Windows. They show logos and colors like that but is is something else. One of my colleagues had this toy and he too at first thought he got Windows mobile for few bucks.

Comment: I didn't notice that, I also heard a lot of guys telling me to they can order fake Iphone with Win Mobile and I sow a few edition witch had a Win mobile as I can realize, Ill today go to mobile shop and take a look on one of those mobiles, to be shore What OS they got and can I write hello word in .net compact framework on that, At my point of view every only feature of moible OS is in Mac, Microsoft and Symbian other shoud be desagred.
Best regards